# What is the meaning of trans_complete in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I found a link where found that

```
$this->db->trans_start();
$this->db->update_batch($table_name, $data, $condition_id);
$this->db->trans_complete();
```

What is return of $this->db->trans_complete()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to find this kind of thing out is to search for the function in question, in the CI code itself.

Your Editor should have the ability to search for "things". In this case - the function of "trans_complete".

The user guide is a little lacking in stating what the return values are.

In CI V3.1.5 for instance, You will find the function trans_complete() in system/database/DB_driver.php

If you check that out - the Docbloc states the return value is Boolean which is either True/False.

If we just want to make doubly sure this is correct, there is a return value of trans_commit() which if you go looking for it, also has a boolean return value.

So in short - Read the code and find out.

The return Value for trans_complete is Boolean ( True if its successful / False if it failed ).

Comment: Your answer clear trans_complete return value. Just another question, is it depends on $this->db->update_batch($table_name, $data, $condition_id);

Comment: The best way to find that out is to try it out... So perform an update batch with some incorrect values ( to make it fail ) and one with everything correct. Inspect the results for each case.

Comment: Thanks, @timbrownlaw